# Where (outside the Rassias Center) can one learn the Rassias method of language teaching?

Tags: teaching-methods

The Rassias method is a language teaching method named after [John Rassias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rassias), who used it at Dartmouth College (in Hanover, New Hampshire, in the United States). The Rassias Center there still uses the method. According to the [description by the Rassias Center](http://rassias.dartmouth.edu/method/):

> The goal of the Rassias Method is to make the participant feel comfortable and natural with the language in a short period of time. This is accomplished through a specific series of teaching procedures and dramatic techniques which seek to eliminate inhibitions and create an atmosphere of free expression from the very first day of class.

The [Teacher Workshops](http://rassias.dartmouth.edu/workshops/index.html) page mentions that,

> The Rassias Method (RM) includes some fifty dramatic techniques that work to banish the inhibitions that can retard the acquisition of foreign languages. RM techniques hold students' attention and foster spontaneous use of the language. Teachers' workshops in the RM offer instructors an array of dynamic classroom activities that use movement, sound, rhythm and motion to help students learn.

There is also an interesting but very short [YouTube video where John Rassias talks about language learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QNZEQ4YeMA).

However, there are very few publications about the method and I could find **whether you can learn the Rassias method at any other place than the Rassias Center at Dartmouth College**. I am especially interested in places in Europe where one can learn the Rassias method (but I'm not very hopeful).

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the Rassias Center directly. They wrote back that the teachers workshops at Dartmouth College take place during the summer and attract educational professionals from around the world, not just from the USA. They currently don't have programs in Europe, although there were some short-term workshops in Europe in the past (with an unnamed partner in Europe).